# Como fazer Botão estilo Material Design apenas com CSS

Tags: css, html5, css3, button, material-design

No Android e no *design system* Material Design é comum ver esse botão que eles chamam de ***Ripple Buttom***. https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/ripple

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porém ele é feito com JS e a minha intenção é faze-lo apenas com CSS. Seria possível fazer um efeito desse tipo apenas com CSS?**

*Repare que quando o btn é clicado dispara esse "ripple effect"...*

**OBS:** Não preciso que o efeito aconteça onde o clique foi feito, pode acontecer sempre do centro do botão para fora. Por isso acredito que é possível faze-lo apenas com CSS nesse caso.

Isso é o que tenho até o momento:

```css
.btn {
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Meu Ripple</div>
```

Comment: hugocsl Da uma olhada nesse codepen, eu acho que responde a sua pergunta.
Está bem simples. Qualquer coisa podemos entrar em mais detalhes! https://codepen.io/finnhvman/pen/jLXKJw Um Abraço!

Answer (score 5):

Dando uma ajustada no CSS consegue fazer um modelo mais próximo do que eu queria.

Ele ativa a animação no clique, e não quando eu solto o botão do mouse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ponto principal é a pseudo classe `:active`, junto com um *pseudo-elemento* no botão que vai fazer o papel do `ripple`. E no `button:active::after` eu ativo o `transition` fazendo o efeito da animação.

Achei que o resultado ficou bastante satisfatório.

```css
button {
    border: none;
    width: 160px;
    height: 140px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #999;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    position: relative; 
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent, transparent);
    background-size: 1%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: background-size 900ms, opacity 150ms;
}

button:active::after {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 50%, transparent 52%);
    background-size: 2000%;
    opacity: 1;
}

html, body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="ripple">Meu Ripple</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Com `transition`s e algum cálculo no background do `radial-gradient` no `hover`.

Edit: que basicamente é o codepen que o @Rodrigo Daoud colocou no comentário, não tinha visto antes de postar a resposta

```css
/* Ripple effect */
.ripple {
  background-position: center;
  transition: background 0.8s;
}
.ripple:hover {
  background: #47a7f5 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, #47a7f5 1%) center/15000%;
}
.ripple:active {
  background-color: #6eb9f7;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}

/* Button style */
button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #999;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="ripple">Meu Ripple</div>
```

[Retirado daqui](http://codepen.io/finnhvman/pen/jLXKJw)

Comment: Amigo quando vc copiar o código de algum lugar, principalmente se for na integra como vc fez, convêm **citar a fonte de onde vc copiou o código** vc não acha que isso seria o correto?

Comment: @hugocsl Claro, tb deixei claro que era do mesmo link no edit.

Comment: Amigo quero que seja o mais fiel ao exemplo, então quero que o "ripple" aconteça ao pressionar o Botão, no seu exemplo ele acontece quando eu solto o botão.... Repare no link que citei. Lá quando vc pressiona o BTN o efeito já acontece e não quando vc solta o btn do mouse!

Comment: @hugocsl nesse caso nã é viável apenas com CSS, pois o CSS não tem um controle de eventos como o Javascript (nesse caso, o evento é `mousedown`).

Comment: Gcp olha ai, com o efeito no clique e não quando solta o btn do  mouse https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/pqEGeO

Comment: @hugocsl é um bom workaround, congrats. Uma pena CSS não suportar eventos diretamente. PS: responda a sua propria pergunta e aceite sua resposta para referencias futuras :)

Answer (score 1):

Fonte: [Material design ripples with CSS](https://ghinda.net/article/css-ripple-material-design/)

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  background: #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  transform: scale(0);
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

button:not(:active):after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}

button:after {
  visibility: hidden;
}

button:focus:after {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Meu Ripple
</button>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que o código faz? Por mais que o código possa responder o que foi pedido, seria interessante explicar como o código funciona para aprendizado de futuras buscas.

Comment: Amigo quero que seja o mais fiel ao exemplo, então quero que o "ripple" aconteça ao pressionar o Botão, no seu exemplo ele acontece quando eu solto o botão.... Repare no link que citei. Lá quando vc pressiona o BTN o efeito já acontece e não quando vc solta o btn do mouse!

Answer (score 0):

Com uma pequena modificação no css e no html da resposta @Netinho Santos, adicionei um JS que faz com que o efeito ocorra a partir do local clicado, assim como no material...
Infelizmente esse efeito não pode ser feito com css puro, mas segue a modificação pra quem tiver interesse:

```js
$('button').click(function(e){

  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.clientX);
  var relativeY = (e.clientY);

  $(this).find('.ripple').offset({top: relativeY, left: relativeX})

})
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

button > .ripple {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;

  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;

  background: #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  transform: scale(0);
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

button:not(:active)> .ripple {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}

button > .ripple {
  visibility: hidden;
}

button:focus > .ripple {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<button>
<i class="ripple"></i>
  Meu Ripple
</button>
```

Comment: Edson valeu a boa vontade, mas consegui resolver apenas com CSS da forma que queria, no clique, e não ao soltar o btn como postaram como os outros códigos.